# How to send in an input to a running command in cmd?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to send a signal to a cash drawer to make it open the drawer.
Its document says that the step is to:

1. Type "TYPE CON>COM1" in command prompt and then ENTER.
2. Type any character(s) and then ENTER.

The problem is that when the first command get executed, the command prompt window waits for an input from user to type anything into it and then ENTER, but tried

1. echo open & TYPE CON>COM1
2. echo open && TYPE CON>COM1
3. echo open | TYPE CON>COM1
4. using the 1-3 choices but with batch files.

Still, I can't achieve what I want. I just want to automate the steps into a single batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution for this.
I use

```
ECHO>COM1
```

and it just works.

Comment: This writes `ECHO is on.` or `ECHO is off.` to the `CMO1:` device; do `echo some dedicated text>COM1` or even better >COM echo some dedicated text`...

Comment: @aschipfl Since it only needs to send a signal to COM1, it can be anything. It can even send a space in and it would still trigger the drawer. So, I decided to have the smallest file size by going for, I think, the least number of characters that make it work.

Comment: Alright, I just wanted to point out what is sent; you could e. g. use `echo/|com` to send just a line-break...